# Перетаскивание нескольких файлов на исполняемый python

Tags: python, drag-n-drop

ДД, господа!
Написал для личного пользования скриптик.
Работает когда файл перетаскиваешь 1. Когда их больше одного то не работает. Скрипт меняет кусок текста в файле на то что введёт пользователь.
Python не знаю совсем. Как реализовать скрипт на множество файлов или на директорию этих файлов не могу нагуглить.

```
import sys

path = sys.argv[1] #получает переменную(он же путь) когда перетаскиваешь файл на исполняемый exe

word = '"twoFA":null' #то что надо менять
new_word = input("введите на что заменить null:") #то на что захочет поменять пользователь
rep = ("\"twoFA\":" + f'{new_word}') #заготовка под replace

#сам скрипт замены для файла
with open(path, 'r') as json1:
    for line in json1:
        line = line.replace(f'{word}', f'{rep}')
        with open(path, 'w') as json1:
            json1.write(line)
```

Comment: а что должно происходить, когда перетаскиваешь несколько файлов?

Comment: Скрипт на замену куска текста срабатывать должен. Тот код что я написал только под один файл так как sys.argv получает путь к файлу когда перетаскиваешь на исполняемый. Но только один путь. Пробовал как то через while но это не работает. Пробовал список создавать sys.argv[1:] но не смог реализовать.

Comment: может как то реализовать зацикленость чтобы sys.argv получал пути всех файлов по очереди пока они не кончаться? Многопоточность в принципе не обязательно реализовывать. Поочерёдно для каждого файла если будет выполняться уже хорошо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sys.argv[1] указывает на то, что мы получаем только первый аргумент запуска файла. Но так как sys.argv является массивом, и все аргументы являются значениями массива, то их можно перебрать:

Перебираем с 1, потому что нулевое значение - это имя запускаемого файла.

```py
import sys

path = sys.argv #получаем массив аргументов

word = '"twoFA":null' #то что надо менять
new_word = input("введите на что заменить null:") #то на что захочет поменять пользователь
rep = ("\"twoFA\":" + f'{new_word}') #заготовка под replace

for i in range(1,len(path)): # Перебиваем массив path, начиная с 1
    
    #сам скрипт замены для файла
    with open(path[i], 'r') as json1:
        for line in json1:
            line = line.replace(f'{word}', f'{rep}')
            with open(path[i], 'w') as json1:
                json1.write(line)
```

Если нужно получить все файлы папки, то импортируем модуль os и немного меняем код:

```py
import sys
import os

path = sys.argv #получаем массив аргументов

word = '"twoFA":null' #то что надо менять
new_word = input("введите на что заменить null:") #то на что захочет поменять пользователь
rep = ("\"twoFA\":" + f'{new_word}') #заготовка под replace

for i in range(1,len(path)): # Перебиваем массив path с 1
    
    files = os.listdir(path[i]) # Получаем массив имён файлов в папке
    for file in files:
        with open(path[i] +'\\'+ file, 'r') as json1:
            for line in json1:
                line = line.replace(f'{word}', f'{rep}')
                with open(path[i] +'\\'+ file, 'w') as json1:
                    json1.write(line)
```

При первом варианте запускаем `python main.py path/to/file1.txt path/to/file2.txt ... path/to/fileN.txt`

При втором варианте запускаем `python main.py path/to1 path/to2 ... path/toN`

Comment: Работает. Благодарностей вагон отсыпал =)